# What is U+215F (fraction numerator one) for?

Tags: unicode

I was looking for a particular Unicode character when I came across U+215F: [fraction numerator one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:U+215F.svg) (⅟)

What on Earth is it for? Is this useful for something in particular (*other* than just for the sake of having a 1 floating over empty space)? Can it be combined, somehow, with other glyphs to create other fractions? Is there actually something under that bar that only really smart people can see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing too fancy, just arbitrary reciprocals.

> ⅟ₓ ⅟₂₃

Comment: Oh. Wow. I had no idea you could do that. ⅟₀ ... hehe.

Comment: To be fair, it depends on the font having a negative trailing kerning for U+215F.

Comment: Aaaand "negative trailing kerning" answers the question *"Is there actually something under that bar that only really smart people can see?"*